# assign roles using moodle core api functions

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I'm creating a block in moodle to assign specific system roles to a user. Not sure the best way to do this..

I know you can assign roles from Site administration > User > Permissions > Assign System roles but my block needs to do other things in custom tables.. I have done the part which creates the record in custom tables but this system role is the only item left..and not sure how to do this

could someone please direct me to how I can do this (assign system roles using moodle core api (functions))

or if its a good idea to add record in the role_assignments table.. manually using database queries? and will it work?

Comment: Hi @davosmith Thank you for this.. yes it works.. Can you please also suggest a site where I can locate these types of core functions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$context = context_system::instance();
role_assign($roleid, $userid, $context->id);
```

Don't directly update the DB table, as that won't trigger event handlers for the role change (or clear relevant caches, etc.).

Comment: Where do you find this method in the moodle documentation? Is role_uassigned accepting the same parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that method in your plugin, that event will be trigger on role assign to user, for a specific course.

```
public static function my_plugin_role_assigned(core\event\role_assigned $enrolment_data){        
    global $DB;

    //strange var name, better change it
    $enrolment_data_data = $enrolment_data->get_data();
    $snapshotid = $enrolment_data->get_data()['other']['id'];        
    $snapshot = $enrolment_data->get_record_snapshot('role_assignments', $snapshotid);

    $roleid = $snapshot->roleid;        
    $rolename = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT shortname from {role} WHERE id = ?", array($roleid));
    $rolename = array_pop($rolename);
    $rolename = $rolename->shortname;

    if($rolename == 'editingteacher'){
        //My stuff
    }

}
```